# Implementing 2D max subarray function as custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, cython

I'm trying to implement a custom loss function in Keras (Tensorflow backend).

My aim is to create a loss function takes y_pred of size (150, 200, 1) (i.e. image of 150x200 with 1 channel), take the difference between it and a corresponding tensor y_true, then scan the resulting "difference" array for subarrays of all possible dimensions that produces a sum with the maximum absolute value (a 2D max subarray problem). Then, the function should output the absolute value of the sum of that subarray as the loss (a float). (I'm trying to model this function on the "MESA" algorithm from this paper: https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2010/Lempitsky10b/lempitsky10b.pdf)

I have been trying to read around custom loss functions in Keras, and I understand that one has to write a loss function within the Keras function space. While I currently have a Cython-optimised version of my loss function, I don't quite know how to translate it into a Keras-friendly version. The code for the main basis of my loss function is shown below.

```py
#The loss function as defined in my code
def MESA(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = y_true - y_pred
    diff = K.eval(diff)
    result = CythonMESA.MaxSubArray2D(diff)
    result = np.array([result])
    result = K.variable(result)
    return result

model.compile(
    loss=MESA,
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

The "CythonMESA" module contains some Cython-optimised functions, which I have attached below. Specifically, the "CythonMESA.MaxSubArray2D" function takes a 2D array as input (such as a 2D np.ndarray object) and outputs a double.

```py
#Contents of CythonMESA.pyx

import numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)

#a helper function that is called within the main function below
#this function computes the maximum sum subarray in a 1D array using Kadane's algorithm
cdef double KadaneAbsoluteValue(double [:] array):
    cdef int length = int(array.shape[0])
    cdef double[:] maxSums = np.zeros(length, np.float64)
    cdef double kadaneMax
    cdef int i
    for i in range(length):
        if i == 0:
            maxSums[0] = array[0]
            kadaneMax = abs(maxSums[0])
        else:
            if abs(array[i]) >= abs(array[i] + maxSums[i-1]):
                maxSums[i] = array[i]
            else:
                maxSums[i] = array[i] + maxSums[i-1]
            if abs(maxSums[i]) > kadaneMax:
                kadaneMax = abs(maxSums[i])
    return kadaneMax

#The main basis for the loss function
#Loops through a 2D array and uses the function above to compute maximum subarray
cpdef double MaxSubArray2D(double [:,:] array):
    cdef double maxSum = 0.
    cdef double currentSum
    cdef int height = int(array.shape[0])
    cdef int width = int(array.shape[1])
    cdef int i, j
    cdef double [:] tempArray
    if height >= width:
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(i,width):
                tempArray = np.sum(array[:,i:j+1], axis=1)
                currentSum = KadaneAbsoluteValue(tempArray)
                if currentSum > maxSum:
                    maxSum = currentSum
    else:
        for i in range(height):
            for j in range(i, height):
                tempArray = np.sum(array[i:j+1,:], axis=0)
                currentSum = KadaneAbsoluteValue(tempArray)
                if currentSum > maxSum:
                    maxSum = currentSum
    return maxSum
```

I've actually tried compiling a network in Keras directly using the above function, but as expected, it throws an error.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to where I can find out how to translate this into a Keras-friendly function, etc. I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple convolution of 1 filter with all-ones followed by a maxpooling would do it.

```
subArrayX = 3
subArrayY = 3
inputChannels = 1
outputChannels = 1
convFilter = K.ones((subArrayX, subArrayY, inputChannels, outputChannels))

def local_loss(true, pred):

    diff = K.abs(true-pred) #you might also try K.square instead of abs

    localSums = K.conv2d(diff, convFilter)
    localSums = K.batch_flatten(localSums) 
        #if using more than 1 channel, you might want a different thing here

    return K.max(localSums, axis=-1)


model.compile(loss = local_loss, ....)
```

### For all possible shapes:

```
convWeights = []
for i in range(1, maxWidth+1):
    for j in range(1, maxHeight+1):
        convWeights.append(K.ones((i,j,1,1)))

def custom_loss(true,pred):

    diff = true - pred

    #sums for each array size
    sums = [K.conv2d(diff, w) for w in convWeights]

    # I didn't understand if you want the max abs sum or abs of max sum
    # add this line depending on the answer:
    sums = [K.abs(s) for s in sums] 

    #get the max sum for each array size
    sums = [K.batch_flatten(s) for s in sums]
    sums = [K.max(s, axis=-1) for s in sums]

    #global sums for all sizes
    sums = K.stack(sums, axis=-1)
    sums = K.max(sums, axis=-1)

    return K.abs(sums)
```

#### Trying something similar to Kadane's (separate the dimensions)

Let's just do this in separate dimensions:

```
if height >= width:
    convFilters1 = [K.ones((1, i, 1, 1)) for i in range(1,width+1)]
    convFilters2 = [K.ones((i, 1, 1, 1) for i in range(1,height+1)]
    concatDim1 = 2
    concatDim2 = 1
else:
    convFilters1 = [K.ones((i, 1, 1, 1)) for i in range(1,height+1)]
    convFilters2 = [K.ones((1, i, 1, 1) for i in range(1,width+1)]
    concatDim1 = 1
    concatDim2 = 2


def custom_loss_2_step(true,pred):
    diff = true-pred #shape (samp, h, w, 1)

    sums = [K.conv2d(diff, f) for f in convFilters1] #(samp, h, var, 1) 
                                                     #(samp, var, w, 1)    
    sums = K.concatenate(sums, axis=concatDim1) #(samp, h, superW, 1)
                                                #(samp, superH, w, 1)
    sums = [K.conv2d(sums, f) for f in convFilters2] #(samp, var, superW, 1)
                                                     #(samp, superH, var, 1)
    sums = K.concatenate(sums, axis=concatDim2) #(samp, superH, superW, 1)
    sums = K.batch_flatten(sums) #(samp, allSums)

    #??? sums = K.abs(sums)
    maxSum = K.max(sums, axis-1) #(samp,)
    #??? maxSum = K.abs(maxSum)

    return maxSum
```

Comment: Hi Daneil! Thanks for your advice. As I understand it this method would return the max sum of all possible subarrays of size (subArrayX, subArrayY), but actually I want to check all possible subarrays of all dimensions and sizes. That's why I wanted to use an implementation of Kadane's algorithm in 2D, as seen in the code I posted. Also, I'd like to keep the signed nature of the contents of the "diff" array while computing the subarray sums, as sometimes elements can cancel each other out and affect the overall sum of each subarray. Is there an efficient way to do all this with Keras API?

Comment: I've updated my question with hopefully more relevant info!

Comment: Does the algorithm calculate all possibilities or it has some intelligence to minimize calculation steps?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thank you for the updated answer. To answer your first question, my original algorithm does limit calculations by employing Kadane's algorithm, which speeds up finding max subarrays in 1D. My algorithm in 2D does an exhaustive search over one dimension while using Kadane's algorithm in the second one to speed up the process. The solution you've provided is very helpful! But I have one question. When taking the K.max, why is axis=-1? I would have thought axis=None because you want to look for the single point in the array with max value, not a column with max sum?

Comment: Also, I have tried the looping conv method but at a size of (150, 200), this takes an extremely long time. If there is any way that this could be done with Keras close to the speed that the original algorithm did it with numpy arrays, I would be very grateful!

Comment: The first dimension of the array is always the **number of samples**, it's not column or row. You don't want to mix the sums of independent samples. That's why `axis=-1` (after a batch flatten)

Comment: See the new answer. Now the convolutions are in two steps, very similar to the algorithm.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. Thank you so much for your kind help Daniel! I understand now more about how the Keras backend works and how to manipulate it to your needs. Cheers!